# How To Get Hidden TD Value when i click on a TR

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im trying to make a task manger based on web system that can monitor tasks at work , im using html and php .
im trying to show all the tasks in table and when i click on a task (row) i want to get a hidden td value (id of task) and send it as arg to another page for more information about the task .
i searched the web how can i do that , but i didnt realy understand how to do it with my table .
here is my table code

```
                   <table id="thickets_show">
                    <tr id="show_ticket_table_header">
                        <td>Work Week</td>
                        <td>Task Submited Date</td>
                        <td>Task Submited Time</td>
                        <td>Task</td>
                        <td>Project</td>
                        <td>Task Owner</td>
                        <td>Task Assigend to</td>
                        <td>Priority</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>Task Total Work Time</td>
                        <td>Task Due Date</td>
                        <td>Task Finish Date</td>
                        <td>Team</td>
                    </tr>';
                    foreach ($tasks as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['ticket_status']=="done")
                            echo '<tr id="done_ticket" >';
                        elseif ($value['ticket_priority']=="high")
                             echo '<tr id="high_ticket" class="ticket_raw">';
                        else
                            echo '<tr class="ticket_raw">';
                        echo '
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['work_week'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_date'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_time_submit'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_request'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_project'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_onwer'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_assigned_user'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_priority'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_status'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_worktime'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_due_date'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['ticket_finish_date'].'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$value['team'].'
                                </td>
                                <td style="display:none;" id="ticket_id class="divOne">
                                    '.$value['id'].'
                                </td>
                              </tr>
```

this is the function that im using

```
$(function(){
            $(".ticket_raw" ).on(\'click\',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr("#ticket_id");
                alert(id);
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$('tr td:hidden')`

Comment: You have a missing double quote: `id="ticket_id class="`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small issue to correct, then you can make this work nice and easily:

`echo '<tr id="done_ticket" >';` is invalid - if you're creating multiple elements in a loop like this, you can't give them all the same "id", that's illegal in the HTML specification. You have to use classes instead.

Rewrite it slightly like this:

```
foreach ($tasks as $key => $value) {
  echo '<tr data-id="'.$value['id'].'" class="ticket ';
  if ($value['ticket_status']=="done")
    echo 'done_ticket';
  elseif ($value['ticket_priority']=="high")
     echo 'high_ticket ticket_raw';
  else
    echo 'ticket_raw';
  echo '">';
  echo '
    <td>
    //etc...
```

Note the extra class "ticket" on the tr element, regardless of the status, and the "data-id" attribute containing the ID (instead of a hidden field).

Now, you can write some jQuery to get the ticket ID:

```
$(".ticket").click(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).data("id"); //gets the data-id value from the clicked tr
  window.location.href = "ticket.php?id=" + id; //example URL to redirect to, passing the ID from the tr
});
```

Lastly you can delete this code:

```
<td style="display:none;" id="ticket_id class="divOne">
  '.$value['id'].'
</td>
```

Comment: @wafihsn no problem, glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The `td` has the id `ticket_id`, so you can use `document.getElementById()`:

```js
var td = document.getElementById('ticket_id');
var value = td.textContent;
```

Or, using jQuery:

```js
var td = $('#ticket_id');
var value = td.text();
```

Comment: i tried it , its keeps getting me the same value over and over

Comment: because you use ID selector and ID should be unique in context

Comment: Yes, that is true. I'd recommend you use what ADyson suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('tr').on('click',function(){
 var hidden_items = $(this).find('.td_hidden');
 $.each(hidden_items,function(k,v){
  console.log($(v).text());
 })
})
```

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
}
td{
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>COLUMN1</td>
   <td>COLUMN2</td>
   <td>COLUMN3</td>
   <td>COLUMN4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>VALUE01</td>
   <td>VALUE02</td>
   <td>VALUE03</td>
   <td>VALUE04</td>
   <td style="display:none;" class="td_hidden">VALUE_HIDDEN_01</td>
   <td style="display:none;" class="td_hidden">VALUE_HIDDEN_02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>VALUE11</td>
   <td>VALUE12</td>
   <td>VALUE13</td>
   <td>VALUE14</td>
   <td style="display:none;" class="td_hidden">VALUE_HIDDEN_11</td>
   <td style="display:none;" class="td_hidden">VALUE_HIDDEN_12</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: what's the point of having a "td" if you're not going to display it? The only purpose of a td is to add something to a table. If it will never be displayed and really contains supplementary data, then it's just abusing the purpose of that element. Instead use a hidden field, or a data-attribute on a another element.

Comment: @ADyson you're wright，when the data we want to save just one attribute, we can add  "data-attribute" attribute to "tr" element,but when we want to save multi attributes, how to play?

Comment: use multiple data- attributes. e.g. "data-id", "data-name" etc, whatever is needed.